# Cucumber, Capybara validating HTML and testing JavaScript together fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara, culerity

I've recently added html validation to my cucumber features.  I'm using the gem be_valid_asset which works really well until Cucumber hits a @javascript flagged feature.  This kicks in culerity (I've tried selenium for this as well) and then the html validation fails.

The reason the validation fails is that both culerity and selenium appear to remove the doctype from the page.

Has anyone else had this?

Comment: Decided to go for a different plan of attack.  I'm switching off the html validation when doing javascript features. When I have a javascript feature I also create a secondary feature that checks the page works without javascript (unobtrusive JS checking) and that feature then does the page validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in strategy mentioned above is working a treat